# How to execute the procedure

Tags: plsql, compiler-errors, ora-06550, pls-00103

How to call the procedure and function from the package?

```
PROCEDURE P_INSERT_PER_LG(IN_DATA DATE,
          IN_CHECK VARCHAR2,
          IN_PSE VARCHAR2,
          IN_TP_CHECK VARCHAR2,
          IN_STATUS NUMBER,
          IN_MSG    VARCHAR2,
          OUT_ERR_MSG OUT VARCHAR2);


FUNCTION F_GT_COD_PTH(IN_CODE IN VARCHAR2)RETURN C_GT_COD_OBJ;
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any package in your question. Also, what is `C_GT_COD_OBJ`? I suspect that is the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

A small sample package:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE TEST_PKG AS 
  FUNCTION Get_Squere(p_num NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
  PROCEDURE Put_Line(p_Text VARCHAR2);
END TEST_PKG;

-- .. and package body
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG AS

  FUNCTION Get_Squere(p_num NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
  BEGIN
    
    RETURN p_num * p_num;
  END Get_Squere;

  PROCEDURE Put_Line(p_Text VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_Text);
  END Put_Line;

END TEST_PKG;
```

And plsql block calling procedure/function from the package

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    m_number    NUMBER(9);
    m_text      VARCHAR2(100) := 'Test - printed out by packaged Procedure...';
BEGIN
    TEST_PKG.Put_Line(m_text);  -- calling pacakaged procedure
    
    m_number := TEST_PKG.Get_Squere(5);   -- calling pakaged function
    
    TEST_PKG.Put_Line(m_number || ' squered is ' || TEST_PKG.Get_Squere(m_number));   -- calling procedure with the value returned by function
END;
/

Result:
anonymous block completed
Test - printed out by packaged Procedure...
25 squered is 625
```